# How to get value before "Delete" on Pop Up menu (right click) is clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

On excel vba, how to run a code before user click **Delete** from **Pop Up Menu** (after right click on row bar)

[image: Delete from Pop Up Menu]

Here is the logic on the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 

If delete (from right click on row) clicked Then

    Msgbox "User want to delete row"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The handler runs *before* a command is selected. It runs before the context menu is even displayed. You could use that to hijack the Delete command / remove it from the context menu and replace it with your own, which you can attach to any macro you like.

Comment: If you simply want to prevent the user from deleting rows, consider configuring worksheet protection instead.

Comment: In my excel file, user is allowed to delete row. But I want to show msgbox before user delete the row.
Is there any way to use other than Worksheet_BeforeRightClick?

Comment: Like I said, hijack the command and replace it with your own "Delete" command, then it can do whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you, it works after I create a new "Delete" command :)